# while compiling below code am getting segmentation fault can you spot me the error for me

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;
    char a[100],b;
    int i=0,j=0;
    fp1=fopen("names.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen("names.txt","w");
    i=0;
    do
    {
        b=fgetc(fp1);
       b=toupper(b);
       a[i]=b;
        i++;
    } while(b!=EOF);
    i=0;
    do
    {
        fputc(a[i],fp2);
        i++;
    }while(a[i]!=EOF);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
}
```

am getting segmentation fault while compiling this code can u plzz help me spotting the error
the error is like"line 2:segmentation fault
"

Comment: Crashes are solved first and foremost by using a debugger to catch it, which help you locate where in your code it happens. Then you can also examine values of all involved variables.

Comment: By the way, [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This is very important for the `EOF` check.

Comment: The error is not stepping through with your debugger before posting on SO, as suggested by @Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: Also, always check the result of system calls like fopen().

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`.   `EOF` is a value that can be represented using an `int`, but not by a `char`.   So, when end of `fp1` is reached, the first loop continues forever, accessing `a[i]` and incrementing `i` every time, because `b` can never be equal to `EOF`.  Eventually it runs past the end of `a` - resulting in undefined behaviour.   Change `b` to be of type `int` and compare its value with `EOF` BEFORE storing in `a`, not after.     The second loop has the same problem, since `a[i]` will never be equal to `EOF`.

Comment: tq but am not getting u

Comment: `am getting segmentation fault while compiling this code` - your compiler crashes?

Comment: Note that you open the file for reading, and then open the same file for writing.  Since the writing version creates an empty file, there is no data left to read.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to debug. Either learn how to use a debugger, or if you haven't got the patience, simply put some debug prints in the code to see how far it is getting. For example:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", i);
```

That will tell you something. You will find the error pretty quickly.

My guesses are:

1. Your file is bigger than 100 characters.
2. b should be an int and you should not store it in the array.
3. The second loop should not look for end-of-file, but should use the count of the number of characters you read.
4. You are closing fp3 but you haven't opened it.

But again, this is basic stuff. You need to learn to do basic debugging.